# Creating a matrix from simple three column text fie

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a matrix or a contingency table from a file that has this format:

```
Species Date Data
1       Dec   3 
2       Jan   4
2       Dec   6
2       Dec   3
```

Result

```
    1  2
Dec 3  9
Jan    4
```

More that I'd like to know how to turn myfile into an array that numpy will like. Basically I'm trying to recreate reshape from R

Hope this made sense. ThanksBlockquote

Made some edits so it might make more sense

Comment: can you please clarify your desired "output" format?

Comment: Nope.  Doesn't make sense.  The number 3 appears in the input, but not the output.  Use **distinct** numbers.  Also post the code you've tried and the problems you're having.

Comment: I'm guessing the 2 and 3 add to 5, but how do you decide the row headings?

Comment: Please tell us the significance of the two columns `1` and `2`, and the conditions under which you are (presumably) adding numbers together (how and why did you get `5`?)

Answer (score 1):

**When other people say "Matrix" you have a dictionary with a two-part key.**

The problem is murky, but you have something like this.

```
matrix = {}
# read input
     matrix[ (row,column) ] = data

row_keys = set( r for r,c in matrix.keys() )
col_keys = set( c for r,c in matrix.keys() )

for r in row_keys:
    print( r, ":", end=' ' )
    for c in col_keys:
        print( matrix.get( (r,c), None ), end=' ' )
    print( end='\n' )
```

[This requires `from __future__ import print_function` for Python 2.7.]

Comment: matrix is a list not a dict. So it has not a keys method.