# Convert three column text file to matrix

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

Hi I'd like to convert a file that's tab delimited and looks like this:

```
Species Date Data
1       Dec   3 
2       Jan   4
2       Dec   6
2       Dec   3
```

to a matrix like this (species is the row header):

```
    1  2
Dec 3  9
Jan    4
```

I'm guessing the part of the solution is to create a dictionary with two keys and use defaultdict to append new values to a key pair. I'd like to spit this out into tab-delimited form but also get into a format so that I can use the cluster part of scipy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a matrix from simple three column text fie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263759/creating-a-matrix-from-simple-three-column-text-fie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/dataframe.html) object in the [pandas](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/) library makes this quite simple.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from pandas import DataFrame

rdr = csv.reader(open('mat.txt'), delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
datacols = defaultdict(list)

# skip header
rdr.next()
for spec, dat, num in rdr:
    datacols['species'].append(int(spec))
    datacols['dates'].append(dat)
    datacols['data'].append(int(num))

df = DataFrame(datacols)
df2 = df.pivot(index='dates', columns='species', values='data')
```

First we read data from a file in the format you provided.  Then construct a dictionary of columns (`datacol`) since this is what panda's `DataFrame` wants.  Once the `DataFrame` is constructed (`df`), then call it's pivot method to get it in the desired format.  Here's what `df` and `df2` look like in the console:

```
In [205]: df
Out[205]:
     data           dates          species
0    3              Dec            1
1    4              Jan            2
2    6              Dec            2
3    3              Dec            2


In [206]: df2
Out[206]:
       1              2
Dec    3              3
Jan    NaN            4
```

You can then use the `toCSV` method to save it to a file (see the DataFrame docs linked earlier).

Answer (score 2):

With pandas its straightforward. You can read your textfile in using read_table() but I have manually created the dataframe below.

```
from pandas import DataFrame    
#create the data frame
df = DataFrame({'Species' : [1,2,2,2],
     'Date' : ['Dec','Jan', 'Dec', 'Dec'],
     'Data' : [3,4,6,3]} )

#group by the Date and Species columns, and take the sume of the Data column
df2 = df.groupby(['Date','Species'])['Data'].sum()

# unstack the Species Column to reshape your data
df2.unstack('Species')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `numpy`, so I can only be of partial help, but i found writing this little snippet entertaining, so here is with defaultdict:

```
# we'll pretend *f* is a file below
f = '''Species Date Data
1       Dec   3 
2       Jan   4
2       Dec   6
2       Dec   3'''.split('\n')[1:]

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for ln in f:
    x,y,n = ln.split()
    d[x,y] += int(n)

# transpose the list of tuples (keys) to get the two dimensions, remove the duplicates
x,y = map(set, zip(*d))

print list(x)
for yy in y:
    print yy, [d[xx,yy] for xx in x]
```

and the result from running this is

```
['1', '2']
Jan [0, 4]
Dec [3, 9]
```

Cute, isn't it?